# Can I control the version of rubygems that IntelliJ uses?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, intellij-idea, rubymine

I'm trying to start a rails application in IntelliJ with the Ruby plugin.

I've imported the application and set up the run configuration as best I can. When I try to run it I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `version_requirements' for #<Gem::Dependency:0x7de21f45>
```

When looking for an answer I found [this page](https://gist.github.com/807008) saying that I should do this:

```
$ gem install rubygems-update -v='1.4.2'
$ gem uninstall rubygems-update -v='1.5.0'
$ update_rubygems
```

Since it's IntelliJ's ruby plugin that is managing the gems, I assume that I have to change the version of rubygems-update that the plugin is using.

Is this the right approach to take? And if so, can anyone tell me how to go about it?

I tried listing the gems but that gem is not shows so I must not be listing the gems in the right place, but I don't know where to look.

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA cannot handle it, you will need to install the appropriate `rubygems` version from the command line.

Note that your current `rubygems-update` version may be different, verify it with `gem list` and use the reported version when uninstalling.

Comment: Run `gem environment` to verify your current `rubygems` version. Try to update to the latest version with `gem update --system`. If it doesn't help, update to the older version as you have described in your question.

Comment: Thank you :) It's getting past that error now. Thank you for your help!